# What is the better way to have a statistical information among the events in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've a project where I need to provide statistical information via API to the external services. In the mentioned service I use only Kafka as a "storage". When the application starts it reads events from cluster for 1 week and counts some values. And actively listens to new events to update the information. For example information is "how many times x item was sold" etc.
Startup of the application takes a lot of time and brings some other problems with it. It is a Kubernetes service and readiness probe fails time to time, when reading last 1 weeks events takes much time.
Two alternatives came to my mind to replace the entire logic:

1. Kafka Streams or KSQL (I'm not sure if I will need same amount of memory and computation unit here)
2. Cache Database

I'm wondering which idea would be better here? Or is there any idea better than them?

Comment: Sounds like Kafka Streams would be a very good solution here. KTable seems to be just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope this is a compacted topic that you are reading, otherwise, your "x times" will be misleading as data is deleted from the topic.

Any option you chose will require reading from the beginning of the topic, so the solution will come down to starting a **persistent** consumer that:

1. Stores data on disk (such as Kafka Streams or KSQL KTable) in RocksDB
2. Some other database of your choice. Redis would be a good option, but so would Couchbase if you want to use Memcached